# Is it a best practice to use inheritance in the spring service layer?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I have two service beans called `PowerUserManager` and `SimpleUserManager`. Both `@Service` annotated classes have about **20% of the code in common**.

I've built an inheritance tree with a common **abstract** class (`BaseUserManager`) to reduce redundancy between the two classes.

```
                               BaseUserManager
                                      |
                               ---------------
                               |             |
                       PowerUserManager  SimpleUserManager
```

Then in my `@Controller` or whatever client class, I use the `@Autowired` annotation to inject both `PowerUserManager` and `SimpleUserManager` and I use one of them depending on the instance of the User I'm dealing with.

I'm not comfortable using **inheritance** to factorize code especially in the **service layer**. Do you Spring fellows see a better way to do this ?

Comment: Are the public interfaces the same, with differing behaviour, or do they have distinct methods that only apply to each type of user?

Comment: @Romski the PowerUserManager have distinct methods that only apply to the PowerUser

Answer (score 3):

You should ask yourself some fundamental questions before considering **inheritance** over **composition** in this case, [and in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance):

1. Are *all* user managers a BaseUserManager? Is this a IS-A relationship in any possible case?
2. Does it make sense to expose BaseUserManager public API everywhere where a user manager is invloved?
3. Does BaseUserManager have a single responsibility?

If the answer is yes, then inheritance is the right way to go. Otherwise, you should probably redesign into several smaller components and treat PowerUserManager and SimpleUserManager as service facades.

Comment: What do you mean by single responsability for BaseUserManager ?

Comment: Does BaseUserManager follow the principles of OOP or is it a messy utility class, that just simplifies common use cases in other managers? For example, if BaseUserManager would be responsible for: permission & role management, registration, account activation, account listing and making coffee, then it might be a good idea, to delegate those tasks to a set of more specialized components.

Comment: @SzymonJednac we have the same situation. we have four(maybe more in future) integrations with accounting software. We are on spring boot, rest api. All of them have common endpoints like addAccount, editAccount, validateCode, validateType, validateName. I used the same approach. One abstract class lets say, AccountService and for each child one like XeroAccountService. I have the same scenario again for their oauth. I am thinking about delegation or composition. do you have any reference I can use? Controller is receiving the callback for all of them but i do not know about the Service layer.

Comment: @MohammadEghlima I'd start a new question, if I were you - it's a different use-case after all (+ you could provide more details about your current approach). That being said, I would avoid sharing code via _inheritance_ in the integration realm (at all costs; external interfaces are likely to change), but also in general. It leads to all kinds of mess in the long run. If you need some inspiration, you should look up `Hexagonal Architecture` as a design pattern. It's not a sliver bullet, but it might help you out.

Comment: thanks. i will read about this design pattern.